# Where to ask about Steemit? (except Steemit itself)

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have some questions about Steemit, so I'd like to try some Stack Exchange site. What would be the best for that purpose?

I was thinking about https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/ (as it is about general blockchain too and Steemit runs on blockchain) or https://webapps.stackexchange.com/, but I'm not sure.

Comment: If speed is your concern, I'm afraid SE isn't the place for you; there's no guarantee whatsoever that you'll get a fast answer.

Comment: "and want to receive help fast," If you want a guarantee of fast help, then posting a question to a volunteer-run site isn't a very safe plan. You would be better off finding paid counseling service for your interest instead of a Stack Exchange site

Comment: Oh people, have I told that I need a **safe** plan? I just believe in SE sites, because I have positive experience with StackOverflow, so I assumed that positng a question in some SE site will be a good idea, maybe better than posting a question on Steemit. Could someone just tell me which site will be the best for such a question? Is it good for Webapps SE or Bitcoin?

Comment: I am shocked the question and an answer already think (by mention alone, you immediatel state) Steem is Bitcoin before Social Network Web App ...I came here to Stack and them Steem entirely for the edit history / audit log. I do not know if that is enough for an answer so I will comment first. I could elaborate but still nervous. Being able to theoretically guarantee post history and memory of your writing is the most important part of Steem, every action is saved, it is a freaking database that matters. The Steem Blockchain/Database is the significant academic factor, stores the actual value.

Answer (score 3):

Given the fact that [9 posts](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/search?q=steemit) about Steemit have already been posted on Bitcoin, as opposed to [0 posts](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=steemit) on Web Applications, it's a reasonable guess to try Bitcoin first. But we can't really tell without seeing the specific question you want to ask. I expect questions about the philosophy of Steemit and how it's built on a blockchain would fly, but questions like 'how do I change my username' (not sure if that's a thing there, I'm just making it up) won't.